Cant play music in react deployed in AWS Amplify

I used amplify to deploy my react app.
In my local the music is working properly but when i deploy it using amplify
Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: The element has no supported sources.
how can i fix this issue
i try to change the naming convention of the filename but still not woking

please check out this post: DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found

Try importing the file.
Verify the promise.

